# Bidirectional DC-DC converter, 12V - 300V, 1 kW?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck, boost, bidirectional

What DC-DC converter topology would you recommend for a device that supports bidirectional power flow of up to 1kW with 300VDC on the high-side and 10-15VDC on the low-side? I want to use it to connect a 300VDC motor/generator to a 12VDC lead-acid battery.

In particular I need a device capable of maintaining the high-side voltage according to a given set-point, irrespective of the power flow direction.

Comment: The function of power conversion from high voltage low current to low voltage high current to be bi-directional is very complex but I would choose non overlapped 4 phase quad half bridge with common choke and 4 star connected phases with ZVRT soft switching to IGBT's.

Comment: As Joe says - doable but potentially complex. I'd start by tending to cheat with two converters and then compare cost & complexity with a true bidirectional converter.

Comment: So do you think it would be doable to get two of-the-shelf DC-DC converters, one buck and one boost and connecting them in parallel with some switches? So that by controlling those switches one could toggle between buck and boost modes and thus adapt to the changing power flow direction?  @Joe, can you provide some more information regarding your proposal?

Comment: Only that 4 phase commutates 1 phase at a time going with 1-2-1-2 round robin number of phases active 3/8th of the time and no more than 2 active on a common core made of torroidal ferrite. Series reactor also needed to smoothen and stored current energy while each phase is discontInuous. I have seen this done on 10kW bi-directional charger. Each driver is a half bridge buck-boost pref. IGBT . Commutation by uC or octal johnson counter with gating for 4 phases.

Answer (score 2):

Chill its only 1Kw so at 300 Volts the average current is about 3.3 Amps. SO you could do your power leveling at the 300 Volt level  There are lots of options so maybe BUCK BOOST or the SEPIC with the 1:1 coupled coil . I did a SEPIC for 1KW on Veroboard making 250VOLT at 4 amp   I used an E65 planar with 6 amp Bifilar Teflon wire and used scrap pcb as a spacer to make the airgap . I used 1200 Volt 80mohm SiC mosfet and got 95% efficiency from rectified mains . SO if you run it backwards you would get a Zeta with the same expected efficiency  .  Now that you can see how easy the high volts is, then you can transform this to your low isolated voltage with a ZVs isolated ROYER oscillator that has a synchronous rectifier to support bidirectional power flow  I would think that you will get better than 90% overall efficiency because I got 92% on 24 Volt NOT 12 and I used 150volt shottkys on the output because I didn't need bilateral power flow . Clearly there lots of ways to do this but I have stated the way that is close to what I have actually done.

Comment: A little formatting & punctuation would make this wall of text so much more readable.

Comment: I will try to type better   next time  sorry

Comment: Or you could just hit edit and fix it. Maybe you'll even get a few up-votes once people can read it ...

Comment: I will try to fix it  my screen name isnt entirely innacurate.

Answer (score 2):

Single-stage basic converter topology is not realistic for this case.  The boost ratio is too large, which results in very inefficient power switch utilization.

You will need an isolated topology here.  I would recommend a three-phase isolated buck-derived topology as shown in this figure.  It is capable of soft-switching due to transformer leakage inductances.  It can be made bidirectional by replacing the rectifier bridge diodes with controllable switches.

It is also a very complex topology and proper simulation and solid design work is recommended.  I have taken part in testing this converter topology (for a fuel-cell converter). The input/output voltages were 30V and 400V.  We achieved ~95% efficiency, which is great for this kind of voltage ratio requirement.  It was not a commercial product, just a prototype.

While the figure seems simple, all three phases interact with each other.

[image]

**Alternative**

Two isolated H-bridges operating in ZVT due to transformer leakage.  This could be the simplest topology.